# Mismatch in the number of ADDITIONAL RECORDS in dig query

Tags: dns, bind, dig

While doing the DNS query through **dig** utility, sometimes i got Additional records in the results while sometimes not. This is very much normal.

But today i saw something interesting in the output of the dig. While querying for **fb.com** domain, i got some additional records in the response.
Interesting part is the information displayed along with flags. 
There dig utility informs that there are **ADDITIONAL: 5** (five additional records) while in the actual output section, it displays only 4 additional responses.

This is not specific to fb.com domain only but i am also getting similar things (mismatch in Additional Section) in other domains too.

```
`[root@Kansal~]# dig fb.com
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P3 <<>> fb.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34411
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 5

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;fb.com.                IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
fb.com.         221 IN  A   31.13.74.36

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
fb.com.         735 IN  NS  b.ns.facebook.com.
fb.com.         735 IN  NS  a.ns.facebook.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a.ns.facebook.com.  3485    IN  A   69.171.239.12
a.ns.facebook.com.  3485    IN  AAAA    2a03:2880:fffe:c:face:b00c:0:35
b.ns.facebook.com.  3485    IN  A   69.171.255.12
b.ns.facebook.com.  3485    IN  AAAA    2a03:2880:ffff:c:face:b00c:0:35

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Oct 20 15:24:59 IST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 183
[root@Kansal~]# `
```

Bind version is 9.10.3

Please explain what i am missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fifth RR in the Additional section is the `OPT` pseudo-RR. Its information is displayed under the `OPT PSEUDOSECTION` header in your example, rather than among the other RRs, since it's special. You can read all about it in RFC 2671.

Comment: Interesting thing.